# Delphi Master Detail cascade ID for new record not working in combination with AutoGenerateValue

Tags: delphi, caching, firebird, master-detail, firedac

Im using RadStudio 10.3.2:
In my VCL Windows forms application I use Firedac database components to make a connection to a Firebird database.

I have 1 Master query component and 1 Detail query component which both have an ID column that uses auto generated values using Firebird Generator.
Both query components have cashedUpdates on for easier/better transaction handling.
Option "Detail cascading updates" is set on on both query components and also on the connection component.

When I add/edit detail records of an existing master record everything works correctly because the ID of the master record does not change anymore.
But when I create a new master record in combination with 1 or more detail records then the DetailField is not updated.

Tried the following 2 examples:

**Example1:**

```
procedure TfrmMasterdetail.btnNewClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  frmnewedit: Tfrmnewedit;
begin
  dmMasterdetail.qryMaster.Insert;
  frmnewedit := Tfrmnewedit.Create(nil);
  try
    if frmnewedit.ShowModal = mrOk then
    begin
      dmMasterdetail.FDConnection1.StartTransaction;
      try
        dmMasterdetail.qryMaster.ApplyUpdates;
        dmMasterdetail.qryMaster.CommitUpdates;
        dmMasterdetail.qryDetail.ApplyUpdates;
        dmMasterdetail.qryDetail.CommitUpdates;
        dmMasterdetail.FDConnection1.Commit;
      except
        on E: Exception do
        begin
          dmMasterdetail.FDConnection1.Rollback;
          raise;
        end;
      end;
    end else
    begin
      dmMasterdetail.qryDetail.CancelUpdates;
      dmMasterdetail.qryMaster.CancelUpdates;
    end;
  finally
    frmnewedit.Free;
  end;
end;
```

**Example2:**

```
procedure TfrmMasterdetail.btnNewClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  frmnewedit: Tfrmnewedit;
begin
  dmMasterdetail.qryMaster.Insert;
  frmnewedit := Tfrmnewedit.Create(nil);
  try
    if frmnewedit.ShowModal = mrOk then
    begin
      dmMasterdetail.FDConnection1.StartTransaction;
      try
        dmMasterdetail.qryMaster.ApplyUpdates;
        dmMasterdetail.qryDetail.ApplyUpdates;
        dmMasterdetail.qryMaster.CommitUpdates;
        dmMasterdetail.qryDetail.CommitUpdates;
        dmMasterdetail.FDConnection1.Commit;
      except
        on E: Exception do
        begin
          dmMasterdetail.FDConnection1.Rollback;
          raise;
        end;
      end;
    end else
    begin
      dmMasterdetail.qryDetail.CancelUpdates;
      dmMasterdetail.qryMaster.CancelUpdates;
    end;
  finally
    frmnewedit.Free;
  end;
end;
```

I noticed once I commit qryMaster then qryDetail does not have a record count anymore. Is there a solution to this problem?
Only thing I can think of is not using the auto generate of the ID value an mannualy fix it when committing, but I rather have everything automatically generated.

By the way Form frmnewedit has data aware controls which handle all data of master record and detail records.

**UPDATE**

I've also enabled option "DetailServerCascade" and added a TFDSchemaAdapter to the query components, but using this I get error "Cannot process - no parent row"

Comment: a) You should retrieve the ID values from the db in the Master and Detail dataset's `OnNewRecord` event and check that you've got them before proceeding.  b) What do you mean by "...  DetailField is not updated"?

Comment: @MartynA with DetailField I mean the Foreign key inside the detail query that links to the primary key of the master query

Comment: Are you using _Centralized Cached Updates_?
http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Caching_Updates_(FireDAC)#Centralized_Cached_Updates

Comment: @UweRaabe no i am not atm.

Comment: The docs in the link imply that you should do that: _Centralized Cached Updates is useful in master-detail relations, where a master dataset propagates changes to the cascading detail datasets, including auto-incrementing field values._"

Comment: @UweRaabe when I add a TFDSchemaAdapter I get an error "Cannot process - no parent row" when adding detail records to the master record.